# Calling a function of a class in the main

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I know we can call a function of a class in the main by the of an object  e.g

```
 object.Function1(object);
```

But is there any way of calling the function like the following

```
  Function1(object);
```

I had to write a class which would run the code with a main function as follows

```
  int main() {
  Line line1(10);
  Line line2 = line1; 
  display(line1);
  display(line2);
  return 0;
   }
```

Comment: `std::mem_fn` is the answer, or a lambda

Comment: Make the method a `static` method.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews if I make the method static  I have to use the class name to call the method

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  You don't need an object instance if the function is static.

Comment: @HaiderImtiaz:  Don't post code in comments, update (edit) your post.  Code in comments is difficult to read.

Comment: just make "display" a free function

Comment: Define another global method 'display' which would call static method of another class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why do you need it but you can create free function "display" that calls method display:

```
void display(Line& line)
{
    line.display();
}
int main() {
    Line line1(10);
    Line line2 = line1; 
    display(line1);
    display(line2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In complement to Sandro's simple but efficient proposal, here a more generic one, mentioned by someone in the comments.

You can create a function object corresponding to the member function, using [`mem_fn()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/mem_fn/) (or [`mem_fun_ref()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/mem_fun_ref/) if you use an older C++ compiler before C++11).

The advantage is that you don't have to worry about return type and parameters:

```
class C {
    public:
    void x() { cout << "Yes x!"<<endl; }
    void y(int a) { cout << "Yes y"<<a<<"!"<<endl; }
};

int main() {
    C c; 
    c.x(); 
    c.y(3); 

    auto x = mem_fn(&C::x);    // function object
    auto y = mem_fn(&C::y);
    x(c);                      // call them like a function 
    y(c,4);

    return 0;
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/CTPcag)

The inconvenience is that this ease comes at a price : Unlike Sandro's approach, you couldn't have different overloads of the same function name for different classes.